# compiling and running mex in Matlab 2013a

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, dll

I'm trying to compile and run a c++ function in matlab. I have Matlab 2013a (64Bit) + windows 7(64Bit) on my laptop. Also I have installed Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1. 
Matlab compiles the function without error, but when running it, it says Invalid mex file '...\filename.mexw64' The specified module could not be found.

what followes is a report of my efforts that may help to solve the problem:
1-after using "Dependency Walker" it shows: ?LIBMX.dll ?MSVCP110.dll ?MSVCR110.dll "Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified(2)."

2-I have LIBMX.dll in "D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64", but when I try to register it, it shows "the module LIBMX.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. make sure that LIBMX.dll is a valid dll or ocx file and try again."

3- I don't have MSVCP110.dll and MSVCR110.dll on my laptop.

Comment: Mex seems to be hellish

Comment: It sounds like the code is relying on an already compiled MEX file called `filename`.  Is there a MEX file you have called `filename`?

Comment: yes, filename is the name of a compiled mex file and I have it on my laptop. but matlab could not find it

Answer (score 2):

mexw32 suggests you did the build of your MEX file with a 32 bit compiler. You need to do it with a 64 bit compiler - recheck your compiler settings for Windows SDK 7.1.

Edit: Other possible problems (if we ruled out 32/64 incompatibility)

Is the path to your LIBMX.dll in your user or system PATH?

Do you have the right Visual Studio Redistributable version DLLs installed?

Comment: excuse me, I have modified my sentence:Invalid mex file '...\filename.mexw64' The specified module could not be found

Comment: Thank you bogeyc for your help. my problem was related to missing MSVCR110.dll. I had installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2010. but when I installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012, the problem solved.